# regex pattern correction required

Tags: python, regex

Input -  I have three kinds of string ending with something different:

```
/nTotal_Cases 63                            73                            21                            157                              12304595%102%129467884%cool LLC Short Term Disability VDT12345 As Of 12/20/2019
/nTotal_Cases 63                            73                            21                            157                             **Please note, PFL premium and claims have
/nTotal_Cases 63                            73                            21                            157                             Note, Sl premium and claims have
```

Required output:

```
/nTotal_Cases 63                            73                            21                            157
```

Query using:

For first kind -

```
re.sub(r'(Total_Cases.+?)\S+%.*$', r'\1', test1, flags=re.S)
```

For the second and third kind:

```
re.sub(r'(Total_Cases([^\*|^a-zA-Z])*).**', r'\1', test1, flags=re.S).rstrip()
```

I'm trying to make a common regex for all these three cases.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this issue? Where *specifically* are you getting stuck in that attempt?

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/fiNqaB/1) OK for you?

Comment: Hi, As you can see using the query i'm not able to drop the extra 12304595 from my string...Do you have any suggestions where I'm wrong?

Comment: Where you are going wrong is matching anything other than a dot or percentage sign as much as possible. It makes sense the returned string include those extra digits. There is probably something neater, but maybe `^(\/nTotal_Cases[\s\d]*?(?=\s*\d*%)).*$` works for you.

Comment: Or, may be [this](https://regex101.com/r/fiNqaB/2)?

Comment: @Toto Yes This one works.. Can you suggest me a way to merge this one with this:            
 re.sub(r'(Total_Cases([^\*|^a-zA-Z])*).*', r'\1', test1, flags=re.S).rstrip()

Answer (score 2):

```
re.sub(r'\S+%.+$', '', test1, flags=re.S)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/fiNqaB/1)

Or, if you want to process only lines that begin with `Total_Cases`

```
re.sub(r'(Total_Cases.+?)\S+%.*$', r'\1', test1, flags=re.S)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/fiNqaB/2)

Comment: Hi, this one works but i'm working on merging the two patterns:   one is below : 
re.sub(r'(Total_Cases([^\*|^a-zA-Z])*).*', r'\1', test1, flags=re.S).rstrip()  with the one mentioned by you...   This is what i'm coming up with:                                                              
re.sub(r'Total_Cases([^\*|^a-zA-Z]*|(.+?\S+%.*$)).*',r'\1',test1,flags=re.S).. But this one isn't working..

Comment: @karan: What are you trying to match? Please, edit your question and add some test cases.

Comment: @karan: To be clear, you want to removes lines that don't contain `digits%....`, am I correct? If it's the case, it will be difficult to combine 2  regex. I think it's better to do the replacement in a second step, then it should be another question.